# what option do i have to execute or communication with native process from Chrome browser using npapi

Tags: c++, google-chrome-extension, native, npapi

I would like to write a Chrome plugin that will communicate with my native C++ process,
to invoke it and capture its return output.

What options do I have in the Chrome browser using npapi? 
im using firebreath for npapi so mybe something with boost?

Comment: ok i guess npapi is the only answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPAPI doesn't restrict you; it's just native C++ code. That means you can use any IPC mechanism that you would used for any two processes. There won't end up being anything NPAPI-specific about what you end up with. (Given that, you might want to ask a new version of this question without mentioning Chrome or NPAPI, since you'll get more answers to a general question about IPC.)

Comment: so i could just invoke or link any library to it ?
like boost or something else and invoke any win32 api from within the browser?

Comment: I'm not a Windows developer, so I can't give you advice on a specific technology. But whatever you would do to spawn a sub-process if this weren't an NPAPI plugin, you should do the same thing in your plugin.